# How does a constructor with 'new' differ from a constructor using 'this()'?

Tags: java, constructor, this

While studying for a Java OCA-examn, I have found it difficult to understand the difference between chaining constructors with *this()* and using *new*. 
Example:

```
public class BirdSeed {
    private int numberBags;

    public BirdSeed(){           
        this(2);                 //  but why not use 'new BirdSeed(2);' instead of 'this(2)' ?
    } 

    public BirdSeed(int numberBags){
        this.numberBags = numberBags;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BirdSeed seed = new BirdSeed();
        System.out.println(seed.numberBags);
    }

}
```

But why not use new BirdSeed(2);, as suggested in the single-line comment, since this will call the constructor and create a new object.

So, given the context above, how is 'this()' and 'new' different?

Comment: `this(...)` allows for code sharing between constructors.

Comment: Because two things are **fundamentally** different. Using new() within a constructor isnt "chaining" at all. That just creates two objects, and opens your door for unwanted endless recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why not use new BirdSeed(2);, as suggested in the single-line comment, since this will call the constructor and create a new object

If you write `new BirdSeed(2)`, you'll create a second instance of `BirdSeed` (in addition to the original instance for which the `BirdSeed()` constructor is executed), and you won't execute the body of the `BirdSeed(int numberBags)` constructor for the original `BirdSeed` instance.

On the other hand, calling `this(2)` executes the `BirdSeed(int numberBags)` constructor body for the original instance.

You can convince yourself of the difference by first running:

```
public BirdSeed(){           
    this(2); 
    System.out.println(numberBags);       // prints 2
}
```

and then running:

```
public BirdSeed(){           
    new BirdSeed(2); 
    System.out.println(numberBags);       // prints 0
}
```

You can also observe the different behavior with the following code:

```
public BirdSeed(){           
    BirdSeed other = new BirdSeed(2); 
    System.out.println(this == other);       // prints false
}
```

As you can see, the instance for which the `BirdSeed(int numberBags)` constructor is executed in not the same instance for which the `BirdSeed()` constructor is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Because `new BirdSeed(2)` creates a *new* (and totally unrelated) object, while `this(2)` calls the corresponding constructor on the current object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new BirdSeed(2) as well, it is perfectly valid. The reason of this() syntax is when you want to initialise a class without any parameter, the default value for numberBags is initialised for you using that this() syntax which is simply calling the BirdSeed(2) for you (however it calls that constructor but it does not create new instance of BirdSeed).